# jScrollPane doesn't scroll to bottom after content update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jscrollpane

I have a chat window with a jScrollPane. The problem is that when I submit a message it doesn't scroll down to the last word/line I wrote, it's always a line behind.

```
$('body').delegate('#private-form', 'submit', function() {
    var sendMessage = $(this).find('input.private-message').val();
    if (!empty(sendMessage)) {
        socket.emit('send private message', {
            'message': sendMessage,
            'username': $(this).find('input.send-to').val()
        });
        $(this).find('input.private-message').val('');
        var data = '' +
            '<div class="person">' +
            '<img src="img/avatar.png" alt="">' +
            '<div class="details">' +
            '<div class="chat">' +
            '<p>' + sendMessage + '</p>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="chat-view">' +
            '<p>10 min ago</p>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';
        var settings = {
            showArrows: false,
            autoReinitialise: true,
        };
        var pane = $('.chat-single');
        pane.jScrollPane(settings);
        var contentPane = pane.data('jsp').getContentPane();
        contentPane.append(
            data
        );
        pane.data('jsp').scrollToBottom();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Markup:

```
<div class="chatters">
    <div class="chat-single">

    </div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.chatters {
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 75%;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 390px;
}

.chat-single{
     height:100%
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After appending the `data`, call `reinitialise` on `pane.data('jsp')` before scrolling to the bottom.

```
contentPane.append(
    data
);
pane.data('jsp').reinitialise();
pane.data('jsp').scrollToBottom();
```

Also, if you're using [`autoReinitialise`](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/settings.html#autoReinitialise) be sure to provide a reasonable [`autoReinitialiseDelay`](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/settings.html#autoReinitialiseDelay) since by default it does this re-initialisation twice per sencond (every 500ms).

Comment: Great!! You the man, what time do you suggest to use for autoReinitialiseDelay ?

Comment: @Uffo In general cases, you shouldn't need `autoReinitialise` and it's delay at all. Check to see if the page works correctly without that property, and if you find that it's unnecessary, get rid of it. Otherwise, if it breaks you site's functionality, I would suggest a delay value of about 2-5 thousand (milliseconds). If you feel that I helped solving your problem, please consider awarding the bounty, because if it gets awarded automatically at the end of the 7 days, only half of it is awarded.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I will reward the bounty in 23 hours, I will not forget, thanks!